# Getting tags from videos with Youtube's XML

Tags: php, xml, youtube, youtube-api

I'm looking for a way to extract tags from the most recent videos of a user via XML and PhP.

It used to work via this type of XML http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/fredy31/uploads but now it seems that the video tags have been removed from that XML file.

So how can I get the video tags from the uploads XML?

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to get every video search tags in an array, for me to use later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tags/keywords are now only returned when you're making a request authorized as the owner of the video: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/08/video-tags-just-for-uploaders.html

Comment: Yes, I read that this morning and then forgot I asked this question. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

YouTube's API can no longer be used to [**retrieve tags**](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/08/video-tags-just-for-uploaders.html) from other users, but you can use the new format to retrieve tags from your own uploaded videos, or any account you have access to.

The video tags should show up in the XML as: 
    `<media:keywords>`

Right after the `</media:description>` if you aren't authorized to access the user account you'll only see this call `</media:keywords>` right after the description. That's what I'm getting from the XML using your account and mine as well. It has to be done through an authorized application using YouTube's API.